# How do we input multiple kernel parameter for the same module?

Tags: kernel-parameters

Lets say I want to put command line args for a kernel module. If the module is some_module.ko.

In modprobe I would go, `options some_module option1=value option2=value`

In kernel command line I would go
`some_module.option1=value some_module.option2=value`

Does repeating the some_module,option2 not override the option1. How do I put them together?

Comment: option2 does not override option1. What makes you think it does?

Comment: I wanted to confirm if it overrides or not, I didn't find any documentation on multiple options

Comment: The modprobe man page makes it clear that you can add several parameters. What happens when you specify the same parameter name more than once, with different values, is not documented and should be considered undefined. It might be possible that different parameters affect each other, but that depends on the kernel module in question, not the modprobe tool.

Comment: thanks it seems to not override so its fine